# Conditional Formatting Across Two Sheets

Tags: excel

Here is what I am trying to accomplish.

I am trying to match a single cell from column A in sheet 1 to any cell in column A in sheet 2. If the strings match, no conditional formatting should occur. But if my cell in sheet one is not found in sheet 2, I want the cell in sheet one to be highlighted as an error.

Example Here: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1k2PBRszYgEsIk7-H3Rtb2era0aKkQ0uqhnYweLvMHp4/edit?usp=sharing

Im not sure where to start? Is this a vlookup? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`VLOOKUP` isn't necessary. I usually prefer `SUMPRODUCT`.

See below, simplified example that conditionally formats any cell in column `B` that does not match any cell in column `A`.

[image]

I realize your question is about two different sheets but I just did an example with one sheet because I can easily show that all in one image.

Only thing to note: I would change the range in the formula (`A:A`), which currently checks the entire `A` column, with a much narrower range that only extends to the end of your data. (e.g. if you have 100 rows of data, replace `A:A` with `A$1:A$100`). This will drastically improve calculation times.